# Implement parallel process in service activator

Tags: spring-integration

In my spring integration application flow is like

Splitter--routter--Service Activator(2 Activators) -- Aggregator

In this ,Will my 2 aggregators work parallelly??
My configuration file is like

```
       <!-- splitter config -->
 <int:splitter input-channel="reqchannel" ref="splitter" method="doSplit" output-channel="routerinput"/>
 <!-- router config -->
  <int:router input-channel="routerinput" expression="payload.isForAct1 ? 'activator1' : 'activator2'"/>
  <!-- service activator 1 cinfig-->
  <int:service-activator input-channel="activator1" ref="processActivator"
                     method="doProcess()" output-channel="processedChannal"/>
 <!-- service activator 2 cinfig -->
  <int:service-activator input-channel="activator2" ref="processActivator"
                     method="doProcess()" output-channel="processedChannal"/>
 <!-- aggregator config  -->
  <int:aggregator input-channel="processedChannal" ref="agrtr"   method="makeAggregate" />
```

Do i need to do any additional configuration to ececute both service activators parallalley??

Please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make channel `routerInput` an `ExecutorChannel` see [ExecutorChannel](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#executor-channel) and [Configuring an ExecutorChannel](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-configuration-executorchannel).

Comment: Thanks @Gary Russell. What would be the advantage if i make activator1 & activator2 channels as Executor channels?. If i configure like this , Will this activators work parallelly?

Comment: You can do that too; it doesn't really matter where you go async. It wouldn't make sense to make them async AS WELL as the `routerInput`; if you make them async, don't make `routerInput` async.

Personally, I prefer to keep it as simple as possible, which would mean making just the `routerInput` async.

Comment: Here can i configure the time taken for service activator?? For eg. if a service activator takes more than 2sec control should go to aggregator or that activator should stop it's process.

Comment: You can add a `MessageGroupStoreReaper` to the aggregrator's `message-store` (`SimpleMessageStore`). The reaper runs on a schedule and "expires" incomplete groups. See http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator

Comment: Thanks @Gary. I could implement using MessageGroupStoreReaper. So the aggregator will not wait for the Activator, that takes long time. But that Activator is running until it end it's operation. Is there any way to stop this activator?? Or can i mention like Activator should stop it's operation if it takes more than 2sec? For scenario like One Activator(task executor size 1) for all operations .Here we need to stop this Activator if it takes long time(>2sec) and start it for next(waiting) operation.

Comment: That would be a function of your code invoked by the `<service-activator/>`. There's nothing the framework can do.